# System.Xml.XmlException: An error occurred while parsing EntityName

Tags: xml, xslt, sqlxml

I am attempting to transform some XML [returned by a sql query e.g. SELECT ... FOR XML  RAW('EmailData'),ROOT('Emails'),type] but for whatever reason just this row is giving me problems:

```
<Emails>
  <EmailData ID="370" C_ID="93" Co_ID="019" MemberName="Twin Cities Orthopedics – Savage" Commit_Program_ID="92" SubmittedBy="9175" AccountExecInfo="Jessica Cooley, jcooley@cc.com" PortfolioExecInfo="Seth Bull, 000.581.5006, sbulling@CCDD.com" SupplierRepInfo="Matt Matts, 000.000.4236 Ext-37, Matt.Matts@ker.com" MemberInfoLink="https://nf.CCDD.com/asp/memberinfo.asp?memid=7893&amp;co=019" DocumentLink="https://nf.CCDD.com/asp/maintanance.asp?doc_id=630" TermsAndCondLink="https://nf.CCDD.com/TermsAndConditions.asp?CPID=92" Doc_Source_ID="BTM" SubmittedByInfo="Automated Tier Update" />
</Emails>
```

The cuplrit seems to be MemberName attribute value ... because when I return an empty string instead of the above value I do not get the exception. Do you see any invalid charecters? Is '-' an invalid charecter for xml?

My XSL Transformation code:

```
public static SqlXml Transform(SqlXml inputDataXML, SqlXml inputTransformXML)
        {
            try
            {
                MemoryStream memoryXml = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
                XmlReader output = null;

                xslt.Load(inputTransformXML.CreateReader());

                // Output the newly constructed XML
                XmlTextWriter outputWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryXml, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
                xslt.Transform(inputDataXML.CreateReader(), null, outputWriter, null);
                memoryXml.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
                output = new XmlTextReader(memoryXml);

                return new SqlXml(output);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( "<error>" + ex.ToString() + "</error>");
                    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream( byteArray );
                    XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);
                SqlXml x = new SqlXml(reader);

                return x;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Robert, The provided XML is well-formed and is loaded OK by a compliant XML parser. The error may be in another record.

Comment: Thanks Dimitre. Do you think that error might be occuring during the transformation and perhaps there might be an issue with the XSLT? I've checked the xslt and I am not seeing anything odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that the hyphen in the member name value is actually an 'em-dash' or an 'en-dash' instead of a normal hypen, which could happen if the data was copy-and-pasted from Microsoft Word, for example, when entering into the database.

Try finding out the ASCII value of the character in SQL. It would be either 150 or 151.

```
SELECT ASCII(SUBSTRING(MemberName, 23, 1)) FROM Member WHERE ....
```

If so, they may need to be encoded in the XML as `&#x2013;` and `—' respectively.

It very much depends on the encoding of the XML. As an example, try opening the following files (which contains both an en-dash and em-dash) in IE and see how differently they are handled

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>
<Emails> <EmailData MemberName="Twin Cities Orthopedics –— Savage"/> </Emails>
```

The above file should work, but the following shouldn't.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Emails> <EmailData MemberName="Twin Cities Orthopedics –— Savage"/> </Emails>
```

Encoding them as `&#x2013;` and `&#x2014;` would work in both cases though.

Comment: You are absolutely correct! Thank you!!! Is there a list of charecters available somewhere that should be encoded? I already am calling System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape but aparently Char 150 isn't encoded by this class.